# GitHub Azure-pipelines check failure (Build #20210302.1 failed)

Tags: azure, github, azure-pipelines

I **pull request**ed a fixing typos in some .md files in a Microsoft repository https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-UXTools-Unreal/pull/28/commits/a371f7627fd562f4f73e5f87c32fc8b179d98e8f all modifications where done using my **Visual Studio** ***Community*** **2019**

After my commit I receive a message "**Some checks were not successful**" the first one is https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-UXTools-Unreal/runs/2009069256

```
Build #20210302.1 failed
1 errors / 0 warnings
 
ANNOTATIONS
Check failure on line 21 in Build log
azure-pipelines / Docs
Build log #L21
PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

If I click to `Check failure on line 21 in Build log` it send me to the three files that I changed, but no one show any thing linked to **Azure-Pipelines**

Lines 21 of each code are:

1st File (Docs/BoundsControl.md)

```
`UxtBoundsControlConfig` data assets are used to configure:
```

2nd File (Docs/PressableButton.md) 21st line is the following

```
Add a [`StaticMeshComponent`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Components/StaticMesh/index.html) (or any [`SceneComponent`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/index.html)) to the actor and set the visuals property of the `UxtPressableButtonComponent` to reference this new mesh. Also ensure that the local positive x-axis of this mesh component points in the direction the button is expected to be pushed. Any component children of this mesh will move along with it as the button is pushed.
```

3rd File (Docs/ReleaseNotes.md) 21st line is empty

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have triggered a pipeline run from within a GitHub action. Check this documentation: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-pipelines-action. Since the pipeline failed, you need to check the pipeline in Azure DevOps to see the detailed log.